# Optimizing PL/SQL code for better performance

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to optimize the pl/sql code given below. Currently I have made a cursor for the code below and I'm looping using that cursor. Is there any other way to improve the performance of the code?

I would also like to know how I can measure the performance of the code (I found out that profiler can be used for this, but I couldn't find how to use the profiler)

```
DECLARE
  TOTAL NUMBER;

BEGIN
  TOTAL := 0;

  FOR ORDERS_ROW IN (SELECT O_ORDERKEY
                     FROM ORDERS
                     WHERE O_CUSTKEY > 4500 AND O_CUSTKEY < 5000 )
  LOOP
    UPDATE LINEITEM
    SET L_COMMENT = 'New comment added'
    WHERE L_ORDERKEY = ORDERS_ROW.O_ORDERKEY;
  
    TOTAL := TOTAL + 1;
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TOTAL);

  ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Comment: `TOTAL := TOTAL + 1;` will increment `TOTAL` in any case, no matter if table LINEITEM was actually updated or not. You may use `TOTAL := TOTAL + SQL%ROWCOUNT;` or just `select COUNT(*) INTO TOTAL FROM ORDERS WHERE O_CUSTKEY > 4500 AND O_CUSTKEY < 5000;` - depending what you are looking for.

Comment: `TOTAL := TOTAL + 1;` and the select statement you wrote gives the same output which is 4959. But `TOTAL := TOTAL + SQL%ROWCOUNT;` and `TOTAL := SQL%ROWCOUNT;` returns 19887 as the output.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE
  TOTAL NUMBER;

BEGIN
  TOTAL := 0;

    UPDATE LINEITEM
    SET L_COMMENT = 'New comment added'
    WHERE L_ORDERKEY in (SELECT O_ORDERKEY
                     FROM ORDERS
                     WHERE O_CUSTKEY > 4500 AND O_CUSTKEY < 5000 );
  
    TOTAL := sql%rowcount;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TOTAL);

  ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

If you run it from sqlplus, then do

```
set timing on
```

before running it. Otherwise, you can get the systimestamp before and after, then subtract.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm getting incorrect output when I run the code though. The value of total is different from the actual value.

Comment: Is it possible to have `NULL` values for `O_ORDERKEY` and/or `L_ORDERKEY`?

Comment: No, they are primary keys and foreign keys so they can't be null.

Comment: what do you mean by incorrect output? especially that you say that the columns in the join are NOT NULL?